# remove duplicates in column 1 of array by retaining only that entry in column 1 that has maximum value in column 2

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique, accumarray

I have a n X 2 matrix which has been formed by appending many matrices together. Column 1 of the matrix consists of numbers that indicate item_ids and column 2 consists of similarity values. Since this matrix has been formed by concatenating many matrices together, there might exist duplicate values in column 1 which I do not want. I would like to remove all the duplicate values in column 1 such that for any value X in column 1 of which there are duplicates, all the rows of the matrix are removed in which column 1 = X , except that row of the matrix where column 1 = X and column2 value is the maximum among all the values for X in the matrix.

```
Example:

  1    0.85
  1    0.5
  1    0.95
  2    0.5

result required:
    1 0.95
    2 0.5
```

obtained by removing all the rows in the n X 2 matrix where the duplicate values in column 1 did not have the maximum value in column 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you might have gaps in the index, use [sparse output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#f78-1048777):

```
>> result = accumarray( M(:,1), M(:,2), [], @max, 0, true)
>> uMat = [find(result) nonzeros(result)]
uMat =
    1.0000    0.9500
    2.0000    0.5000
```

This also simplifies creation of the first column of the output.

---

A couple of other ways to do it with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

First way, use `sort` with `'descend'` ordering:

```
>> [~,IS] = sort(M(:,2),'descend');
>> [C,ia] = unique(M(IS,1));
>> M(IS(ia),:)
ans =
    1.0000    0.9500
    2.0000    0.5000
```

Second, use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) (ascending sort by second column), and `unique` with `'first'` occurrence option:

```
>> [Ms,IS] = sortrows(M,2)
>> [~,ia] = unique(Ms(:,1),'last')
>> M(IS(ia),:)
ans =
    1.0000    0.9500
    2.0000    0.5000
```

Comment: Yep - after posting my original answer I had a chance to try some stuff and discovered that using sparse is the way to go. But you posted that before I could come back and update my answer...

Comment: I don't like the expanded answer as much as I liked the original.

Comment: @Floris Me neither, to be honest. I just wanted to put some other options out there. Would it have been smarter to put the extra stuff in a different answer? Sometimes clutter can be a negative.

Comment: @chappjc, Floris, the sparse seems to be the way to go for me as well, its much more concise than my answer. Thanks to both of you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
result = accumarray( M(:,1), M(:,2), [max(M(:,1)) 1], @max);
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), that should work.

Apologies I can't try it out right now...

**update** - I did try the above, and it gave me the max values correctly. However it doesn't give you the indices corresponding to the max values. For that, you need to do a bit more work (since the identifiers probably aren't sorted).

```
result = accumarray( M(:,1), M(:,2), [], @max, true);  % to create a sparse matrix
c1 = find(result);     % to get the indices of nonzero values
c2 = full(result(c1)); % to get the values corresponding to the indices
answer = [c1 c2];      % to put them side by side
```

Comment: I don't think the solution works as written above but I will try looking into the accumarray function. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @user1009091 - as written my solution gives "half an answer". Using the `issparse` parameter as shown in chappjc's answer gets you the rest of the way.

Comment: I decided to finish the "update" I had started (I found it half-finished in another browser window) just to clear things up a bit. No need for sorting or `unique` after you use the sparse matrix approach. I think this is the most "matlab like" solution now.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = accumarray( M(:,1), M(:,2), [max(M(:,1)) 1], @max);

finalResult = [sort(unique(M(:,1))),nonzeros(result)]
```

This basically reattaches the required item_ids in sorted order to the corresponding max_similarity values in the second column. As a result in the finalResult matrix, each value in  column 1 is unique and the corresponding value in column 2 is the maximum similarity value for that item_id.
@Floris,  thanks for your help couldn't have solved this without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach: use `sortrows` and then `diff` to select the last row for each value of the first column:

```
M2 = sortrows(M);
result = M2(diff([M2(:,1); inf])>0,:);
```

This works also if the indices in the first column have gaps.